# How to listen for changes in values of nest device parameters in c# console application?

Tags: c#, nest-api

I am working on a c# code where whenever there is any change in parameters of nest device, a message must be put on the command line.
For eg : If the humidity of thermostat changes from 50 to 67. a message must be written on to the console saying "change in humidity".
May need to continuously listen to nest device. Can anyone give me a head start like if there are any api's that i should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below, this should give you a head start..

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818265/NET-Works-with-Nest-Guide-to-calling-Nest-API-fro

You can witness the real time updates using FireSharp whenever you  change the temperature in the nest simulator.

Comment: Latest FireSharp Nuget doesn't allow to create new object of Firebase due to permission levels. Tried with old version of the package, yet didn't work out